# Windows 7 can see Server, but not its contents

Tags: server, windows-7, samba

I'm a newbie to Ubuntu so I apologize if I'm overlooking something easy, but I installed Samba and for whatever reason I can see my Ubuntu server on my Windows 7 computer, but when I click on it I cannot seem to pull up anything on it.  Any ideas?

Comment: you should post your smb.conf file

Answer (score 1):

You could edit your /etc/smb.conf file... use your favorite text editor:

```
sudo vim /etc/smb.conf
```

Uncomment/supply values for these:

```
workgroup = your_workgroup
security = user # real unix users
encrypt passwords = true
passdb backend = tdbsam
obey pam restrictions = yes
SO_RCVBUF=8192 SO_SNDBUF=8192
socket options = TCP_NODELAY
[homes]
    comment = Home Directories
    browseable = yes
    read only = no
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    valid users = %S
```

And maybe add other shares at the end of the file...

```
[backup]
    comment = Backup Disk
    writable = yes
    path = /mnt/backup/
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    valid users = root @admin @backup # only root, group admin, and group backup
```

Save then restart samba

```
sudo restart smbd
```

Now you can map drives with the same credentials you use for Ubuntu.
Success?